# Run two commands at the same time in Elm

Tags: javascript, elm

In `Elm`, and specifically with the [Elm Architecture](http://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/) when the app first starts the `init` function can return a `Cmd Msg` that is executed. We can use this for sending http requests or send a message to native Javascript via [Elm ports](http://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html).

My question is, how can I send multiple commands that should be executed in `init`?

For example I can do something like:

```
init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  (Model "" [], (Ports.messageToJs "Hello JS"))
```

And I can do something like:

```
url : String
url =
     "http://some-api-url.com"
...

fetchCmd : Cmd Msg
fetchCmd =
    Task.perform FetchError FetchSuccess fetchTask


init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  (Model "" [], fetchCmd)
```

**How can I return both commands at same time from `init`?**

I have seen `Task.sequence` and even `Task.parallel` but they appear to be good for running multiple tasks, not specifically commands.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use `Platform.Cmd.batch` ([docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Platform-Cmd#batch)):

```
init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  ( Model "" []
  , Cmd.batch [fetchCmd, Ports.messageToJs "Hello JS")]
  )
```

Comment: Do commands run in parallel or are they serialized?  I'm thinking of a batch of multiple HTTP gets that would take a long time if serialized.

Comment: @goertzenator they run in parallel, not in series

Comment: The order is not specified. As JavaScript runs with a single thread one will run before the other, but you should not make any assumptions about what that order will be.

Answer (score 5):

Do as Sören says, or use the newer, equivalent "bang" -syntax :

```
init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  ( Model "" [] )
  ! [fetchCmd, Ports.messageToJs "Hello JS"]
```

Comment: [bang syntax docs - v5.1.1](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Platform-Cmd#!)